# Pósa's inequality for a product of consecutive primes

Tags: nt.number-theory

Is it posible to find the article "Pósa Lajos, A prímszámok egy tulajdonságáról (Hungarian), Mat. Lapok 11 (1960), 124-129" on the internet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, here is the archive of [Matematikai Lapok](http://real-j.mtak.hu/view/journal/Matematikai_Lapok.html).

Comment: Thank you, it is very useful for my purpose.